# Different syntax's for defining a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

I'm working through a book on javascript, and on one of the examples they are displaying these two blocks of code to be used in the example:

```
    showTipListener: function(event)
    {
        Tooltips.showTip(this);
        Core.preventDefault(event);
    }
    hideTipListener: function(event)
    {
        Tooltips.hideTip(this);
    }
```

and

```
    var Tooltips = 
    {
        init: function()
        {
            var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

            for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
            {
                //Every link is going to need a title attribute in the HTML
                var title = links[i].getAttribute("title");

                if (title && title.length > 0)
                {
                    Core.addEventListener(links[i], "mouseover", Tooltips.showTipListener);
                    Core.addEventListener(links[i], "focus", Tooltips.showTipListener);
                    Core.addEventListener(links[i], "mouseout", Tooltips.showTipListener);
                    Core.addEventListener(links[i], "blur", Tooltips.showTipListener);

                }
            }
        }}//I also had to add this extra closing bracket to avoid errors? Don't understand why
    }
```

What I'm worried about is where does the first code sample go in reference to the second code sample?

I've never used this syntax before (as seen in the second code sample) to define a javascript function:

```
    functionName: function(passedParam)
    {
        //function body
    }
```

The above is just an example, not part of my code.

Maybe these functions are to be inside of the Tooltips object? This was a thought of mine, so I did it, put the two functions inside of the ToolTips object's brackets. Now, I get this error in FireBug:
[image: My FireBug error]

I'm just looking for any help and guidance anyone has to offer. I'm not new to javascript, but am new to defining functions this way.

Comment: Perhaps you should finish reading that chapter - http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9780980285802/events/sect-tooltips#title-ID0EE3AG

Comment: Sorry Phil, I didn't even follow the link, thanks for the response though

Answer (score 2):

Take a look:

```
var whatever = {                  //object
    add: function(a, b){            //function 1
        return a + b;
    },
    minus: function(a, b){          //function 2
        return a - b;
    }
}

whatever.add(1,1); //returns 2
whatever.minus(1,1); //returns 0
```

This is *not* a new way of defining functions. This is just setting a property (or whatever you call it) of an object to be a function, which is similar to this:

```
var whatever = {
    city: "NYC",
    date: +new Date()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The two top functions are obviously members of the `Tooltips` object as that is how they are invoked in your second snippet. See

```
Core.addEventListener(links[i], "mouseover", Tooltips.showTipListener);
```

Your first snippet would make more sense as

```
var Tooltips = {
    showTipListener: function(event)
    {
        Tooltips.showTip(this);
        Core.preventDefault(event);
    }
    hideTipListener: function(event)
    {
        Tooltips.hideTip(this);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

hey I would look at these two resources. They have some great tips  on how to better write javascript

https://github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js/

http://shichuan.github.com/javascript-patterns/

Comment: in response to op statement "I'm just looking for any help and guidance anyone has to offer."